# Django write to database, IntegrityError

Tags: django, postgresql, ubuntu, model, django-south

My webpage's *signup* view (below) creates a new user through Django's auth model, *User*, then uses that newly created user's ID to add more info through my own model, *account.Users*. My problem is that, though I am passing the new user's ID to the second model (the ForeignKey column in *account.Users*), I keep getting an error that column *user_id* violates a not-null constraint:

```
IntegrityError at /account/signup/ 
null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
```

Here are the relevant parts of my model:

```
class Users(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
  firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
```

And the relevant parts of my view:

```
def signup(request):
  if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST['firstname']:   
    user = User.objects.create_user(request.POST['username'], request.POST['email'], request.POST['password'])
    userId = user.id
    form = UsersForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
      cmodel = form.save()
      cmodel.user_id = userId
      cmodel.firstname = request.POST['firstname']
      cmodel.save()
```

What could be the reason for this error?

Aside from setting *cmodel.user_id* equal to *userId*, I have also tried setting it equal to the *user* object created in the first step, as well as a string and int ('1' and 1, respectively). I get the same error each time. I have also tried changing the field to *cmodel.user*. I can also tell from Django's error page that the variable *userId* does in fact contain a value.

Comment: Another potentailly relevant piece of info: I've also restarted apache and postgres.

Comment: Did you double checked the table's schema in Postrgres, maybe you created it first without `null=True` and later fixed it but never actually updated the schema.

Comment: It has always had null=True

Comment: This format used to work, until I changed a some other parts of the code, one of which was installing PIL (Python Image Library) and adding an image field, could this have something to do with it? (I don't see how it could)....

Comment: Not likely, still, be 100% positive that the schema in the database allows null. Not rely only on the model.

Comment: Just checked (this time through my PostgreSQL client, Navicat) and it shows that it allows Null and the default value is 0

Answer (score 1):

The solution was simple, albeit unexpected. I'm writing it up here in case anyone else runs into the same issue:

In addition to the summarized portion of the model I showed above, I was also trying to save an image with [PIL (Python Imaging Library)](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/%E2%80%8E). Adding that to the relevant portion of the model shown above:

```
class Users(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
  firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
  profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profilepics', max_length=300, default='')
```

This "upload_to" folder, "*profilepics*", had the access permissions "755", but when I changed them by running "$ chmod -R 777 profilepics" in the terminal, everything worked! Strange that the error message was blaming it on my the "user_id" field being null. It was really just a folder permission for something entirely different. Hope that helps somebody, someday.